# Ubuntu starting scripts

Tags: 14.04, login

My Ubuntu 14.04 has RemoteControlServer running. When I login the program asks to update. I would like to disable the program, but I haven't been able to find the file that invokes it. Where are all the startup files where I can start applications on login?

inxi returns:

```
 System:    Host: i7bobby Kernel: 3.13.0-55-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) 
               Desktop: Gnome 3.10.4 dm: lightdm Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
    Machine:   Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z68MX-UD2H-B3 version: x.x Bios: Award version: F3 date: 05/02/2011
    CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-2600 CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 27139.9 
               Clock Speeds: 1: 1600.00 MHz 2: 1600.00 MHz 3: 1600.00 MHz 4: 1600.00 MHz 5: 1600.00 MHz 6: 1600.00 MHz 7: 2300.00 MHz 8: 1600.00 MHz
    Graphics:  Card: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0102 
               X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@59.9hz 
               GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Desktop GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Applications are typically stored as **.desktop** files in the `~/.config/autostart` folder.

Locate the above folder; if `RemoteControlServer` uses this folder to store it's startup script, then you'll see it - in which case you can simply delete the file.

Alternatively, you can search "startup applications" into the Dash and open the program `Startup Applications`; locate the `RemoteControlServer` option and disable it.